# Create excel sheet without using Activexobject in js

Tags: javascript, jquery, excel

I am trying to parse a xml and put the content of the xml into the excel sheet.
I have the limitation to use only javascript/jquery and moreover the application is standalone for which this plugin is created.
I tried

```
var excel = new ActiveXObject ( "Excel.Application" );
excel.visible = true;
var book = excel.Workbooks.Add;
book.Worksheets.Add;
book.Worksheets(1).Activate;
book.Worksheets(1).Cells(1,1).value="My First Spreadsheet";
book.Worksheets(1).SaveAs("C:\\excel_file.XLS");
```

but this didn't worked as Activexobject works only in IE with Windows.
Is there any other option to develop it.
The standalone application is in java.

Comment: I haven't used it myself, but you could take a look at xlsx.js: http://blog.innovatejs.com/?tag=xlsx-js